# Why didn't Voldemort kill Harry at King's Cross?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

Why didn't Voldemort, with his Death Eaters, attack Harry at the train station in *Order of the Phoenix* or in *Half-Blood Prince*? He could have easily outsmarted the wizards and witches there with the help of his Death Eaters, or he could have just Disapparated after killing Harry.

Comment: Is this based on the books or movies? I seem to remember the movies inserting some ludicrous scene where Harry see's Voldemort in the train station, wondering if that's what prompted the question.

Comment: @DavidS No connection, I was asking in a different perspective. Not at all related to book or movie. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the fifth part, Voldemort was doing his best to keep hidden, which makes things easier for him if no one believes he came back, and because of the history, he wanted to be the one who kills Harry. In that case, it would not have been very realistic of him to suddenly appear at the King's Cross, nor would he want his Death Eaters to do the job for him. Even at the end, surely it was not part of his plan to be seen by Fudge and the others.

In the sixth book, we can make some assumptions, especially based off of this part:

> “Ah, Harry!” said Mrs. Weasley loudly, cutting across Fleur’s
>   monologue. “Good, I wanted to explain about the security arrangements
>   for the journey to Hogwarts tomorrow. We’ve got Ministry
>   cars again, and there will be Aurors waiting at the station —”
>
> “Is Tonks going to be there?” asked Harry, handing over his
>   Quidditch things.
>
> “No, I don’t think so, she’s been stationed somewhere else from
>   what Arthur said.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 7: *The Slug Club*.</sub>

Given that, it's safe to believe that the travel to King's Cross as well as the station itself is being watched by a highly capable set of Aurors, again, which would be a very messy situation for even Voldemort and his friends to deal with. Hence the elaborate plan involving Dumbledore and such.

Comment: A small correction. The cursed necklace wasn't meant for Harry. It was meant for Dumbledore. Draco Malfoy was given the job to kill Dumbledore by Voldemort. He tried to achieve it by Imperiusing Katie Bell into delivering the necklace to Dumbledore. The poisined mead that Slughorn accidentally fed Ron was again meant to be a gift for Dumbledore. Voldermort explicitly ordered all of his followers not to kill Harry since he(Voldemort) wanted to be the one to do it.

Comment: hmm hmm... Voldemort should have comparable skills to Dumbledore (if not equal), And Dumbledore could have undertook a whole army of Aurors single handedly. Couldn't Voldy have done the same? I am talking about6 part..

Comment: @prakharlondhe There's no evidence that Dumbledore could have taken on an army of Aurors, especially ones prepared to take him down. Also, if the battle had gone on more than 20 seconds, *guess who'd show up to help*.

Comment: In OOTP, "I am ready to fight your aurors. And win Again, but you have already saw that you have been chasing the wrong person all the time....." Dumbledore to Fudge.

Comment: red_devil226: Whoops, you're right, I must have gotten confused there.

Comment: @deworde take a look at my comment...

Comment: @prakharlondhe Dumbledore saying "I am ready to fight and win again" merely means he fought and got away, as he did the time before. Also, "something Dumbledore said to intimidate Fudge" is not the same as actual established fact. And read the last of mine. I suspect Dumbledore might have been less sanguine if Voldemort had stuck around to back up the Aurors.

Comment: But Dumbledore don't just boast something to intimidate fudge, Dumbledore always gives undeniable facts, And Aurors won't back up Voldy at all, indeed when some of the aurors respect Dumbledore very highly.

Comment: Also what about the time when Harry was with the dursleys but out of the house? For example while travelling to home from the station, in the car?

Answer (score 9):

It isn't clearly claimed, but I think that the most important places of magicians were protected some way (aurors, magic, maybe Dumbledore). Voldemort appears at the Ministry in the end of book V and we can see that it's dangerous for him too.

Anyway, many of the death eaters and their children are usually in King's Cross by the departure. It would be dangerous for them to start a fight there - and of course the attack would be obvious if these people were missing.

Comment: What about when they were entering the station in the 6th part?

Answer (score 1):

There would be too many adults there and so Harry would be protected, and there would be a lot of Muggles and they could tell someone and he would be defeated. Although people are scared of him, they would protect their children due to motherly and fatherly instinct.

Answer (score 1):

## King’s Cross is watched by the Ministry.

The Dark Lord didn’t only have to defeat whatever guard Harry himself came with - there would be several Ministry employees around King’s Cross to make sure no Muggles see anything magical.

> On the whole, this has worked well, although there have been minor problems over the ensuing years, such as witches and wizards who have dropped suitcases full of biting spellbooks or newt spleens all over the polished station floor, or else disappeared through the solid barrier a little too loudly. There are usually a number of plain-clothed Ministry of Magic employees on hand to deal with any inconvenient Muggle memories that may need altering at the start and end of each Hogwarts term. 
> <sub><sup>*[- King’s Cross Station (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/kings-cross-station)*</sup></sub>

If the Dark Lord or the Death Eaters showed up there, these Ministry employees would almost certainly call in Aurors. Also, they’d likely take an attack at King’s Cross even more seriously than one at a wizard-only place because if the Dark Lord and the Death Eaters start using magic around Muggles, which they probably would be if trying to attack Harry, it could violate the Statute of Secrecy. Because of that, the Ministry is likely to take more decisive action to stop them, so it’d be far riskier for the Dark Lord and the Death Eaters to try attacking Harry there.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, it is because he was scared. Remember that after the fight in the graveyard of Little Hangleton Voldemort does not understand why he was defeated by Harry twice. He is hunting for the prophecy in the 5th book, and without hearing it he is very wary of attacking Harry. What if he 'dies' again? That would set him back another 12 years. That would suck.

In the sixth he still has not found the answer to why Harry keeps beating him. In fact, he was beaten almost worse in the 5th book. So, he wants Olivander, he wants the power of the ministry. He wants Dumbledore out of the way. All *before* he kills Harry. Notice that after the 4th book the only time he actually tries to kill Harry is in the 7th book, when he thinks a different wand will work, and after he obtains the Elder wand.

Comment: Voldy tried to kill Harry everytime he got a chance... In the fight in the graveyard, he tried to kill harry, even without knowing the full prophecy. Your answer is not at all close.

Comment: What are you on about? If you read my answer or the books you would know that he is not scared of Harry until AFTER the fight in the Graveyard, when Harry's wand conquers Voldemort's. It is this event that triggers Voldemort's search for the prophecy. He goes to the ministry assuming he will hear the prophecy and kill Harry, which he is mistaken. The next time he tries to kill Harry is almost two years later, when he has Malfoy's wand, believing at that point that only the twin cores made him lose in the graveyard. After that, he does not spend his time hunting Harry.

Comment: He instead spends his time hunting the Elder wand, believing that only the Elder wand will allow him to kill Harry. The question is why Voldemort doesn't seek extra battles with Harry. Why he never intercepts the Hogwarts express, why he never tries to find him in Diagon Alley. He certainly duels to kill when he is face to face with Harry already, but he never actively seeks fights with Harry unless he believes he already has the upper hand, which he does not (in his mind at least) for much of the 5th and 6th books, because he lacks information about the prophecy and then the twin cores.